# regex for appending text using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have text that looks like this

> HELLO WORLD (some_text, some_other_text)

I want to append a number say 16 at the end to the above text like this

> HELLO WORLD (some_text, some_other_text) 16

I know this regex `^HELLO WORLD \(([a-z],[a-z])` matches it .
I am not sure how to store the regex matched in a variable and then append 16 to it.

Comment: What's the context in which this sed script will be run?  [What are you REALLY trying to achieve?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `&` character holds everything in the pattern space:

```
sed 's/^HELLO WORLD ([a-z_]*, [a-z_]*)/& 16/' file
```

Take a look at [Using & as the matched string](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3)

And [Using \1 to keep part of the pattern](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)

Comment: **+1** ... except I feel I've been cheated out of a `FNR==NR`.

Comment: @ghoti: Lol, sorry about that :P  I'll try and add one in my next answer.

Comment: Steve thanks for the answer and also for being a gentle teacher