# Use sed to append text after start marker with text block until end marker

Tags: bash, sed

I have a report (simple text file) that needs to be updated (via bash) for service consumption.

The report consists of lists of categories each with a list of items, something like the following example:

```
vehicle:
car
moto
done

fruit:
banana
apple
done

tree:
pine
oak
done
```

The purpose of the update is to add new items after the last of a specific category:

> Add `orange` to `fruit` after `apple`

For this I've created a small sample script to test/debug this procedure/update using `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=report.txt

cat > "$file" << EOT
vehicle:
car
moto
done

fruit:
banana
apple
done

tree:
pine
oak
done
EOT

category="fruit"
append="orange"

## only $category has $append - but at start:
#find_lhs="^$category:"
#replace_rhs="$category:\n$append"

## all categories have $append at end:
#find_lhs="([\S\s]*?)done"
#replace_rhs="\1$append\ndone"

# add $append at the end of $category - nothing happens:
find_lhs="^$category:([\S\s]*?)done"
replace_rhs="$category:\n\1$append\ndone"

sed -i -E "s/$find_lhs/$replace_rhs/g" "$file"

cat "$file"
```

---

#### Question:

What is missing/failing with:

```
sed -i -E "s/^$category:([\S\s]*?)done/$category:\n\1\n$append\ndone/g" "$file"
```

to produce the following report content:

```
vehicle:
car
moto
done

fruit:
banana
apple
orange #<-- inserted
done

tree:
pine
oak
done
```

??

---

**Disclaimers:**

- already tried:

  - [sed: Appending after a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54385546/9403724)
  - [use sed to insert a line after matching a block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183516/9403724)
  - [regex for appending text using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13170681/9403724)
  - ... and others...

    - *but probably not in the correct way...*
- aware that using `awk`, `perl`, `python` or other tools/languages would be much simpler

  - *but why not just use `sed`?!*

Comment: @anubhava updated the question with the expected output

Comment: your items are unique. `sed '/^apple/a orange' your_file`

Comment: they can be unique, but not aware of any pre-existing content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "/$category/,/done/{/done/s/^/$append\n/}" <<< "$file"
```

```
$ sed "/$category/{:a;/done/s/^/$append\n/;n;/^$/!ba}" file
```

```
$ sed -e "/$category/{:a;/done/i$append" -e 'n;/^$/!ba}' file
```

***Output***

```
vehicle:
car
moto
done

fruit:
banana
apple
orange
done

tree:
pine
oak
done
```

Comment: tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and the file didn't change

Comment: @mo7ty Just tested on 20.04 and it works for me.  Did you copy and paste correctly? I see in the code you used, you use in place editing which can only be used on a file, so is your data in a file or variable? If file, please remove the redirect

Comment: Another `sed` solution `sed -e "/$category/{:a;/done/i$append" -e 'n;/^$/!ba}' file`

Comment: your two last options indeed print in the console the expected result, but the report file itself is not modified

Comment: @mo7ty That would be because you have not included the `i` in place flag. `sed -i "/$category/{:a;/done/s/^/$append\n/;n;/^$/!ba}" file`. I assumed you were aware of this as it is in your original code.

Comment: It works! The only update I was doing was to ref the report var `$file`.
What if there are empty lines before `done`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245152/discussion-between-mo7ty-and-hatless).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/fruit:/,/done/{/done/i\orange' -e '}' file
```

Focus on the fruit category and insert `orange` before the category delimiter i.e. `done`.

N.B. The solution is in two parts as the `i` command expects a newline or another command set.

Alternative:

```
sed '/fruit:/,/done/!b;/done/i\orange' file
```

Comment: After some tweaks, also solves the problem! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here is a `gnu-awk` that does the job using custom `RS`:

```bash
awk -v append='\norange' -v category='fruit:' -v RS='\ndone\n' '
{ORS=RT} $1 == category {$0 = $0 append} 1' file

vehicle:
car
moto
done

fruit:
banana
apple
orange
done

tree:
pine
oak
done
EOT
```

To save change into the same file use:

```bash
awk -i inplace -v append='\norange' -v category='fruit:' -v RS='\ndone\n' '{ORS=RT} $1 == category {$0 = $0 append} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you, but the purpose is to just use `sed`

Comment: It is your choice to use whatever tool you want to but purpose should to solve the problem in best possible way.